# Setting image for MKAnnotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation

I added MKAnnotation in my mapview using the following code.

```
Flag *flag = [[Flag alloc] init]; 
flag.title = @"Golf Course";
flag.subtitle = @"Green"; 
flag.coordinate =CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(28.457394,77.108667);
[mapView addAnnotation:flag];
```

and am setting image like

```
 -(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:
 (id <MKAnnotation>)annotation 
 {
   if(([annotation isKindOfClass:[Flag class]])) 
   {
      MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = nil; 
      if(annotation != mapView.userLocation) 
      {
        static NSString *defaultPinID = @"PinId1";
        pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        if ( pinView == nil ) pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                          initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pin1"] autorelease];

        //pinView= [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pin1"];

        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
               pinView.draggable = YES;
        [pinView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flag2.png"]];

     } 
     else 
     {
        [mapView.userLocation setTitle:@"I am here"];
     }

   }
    return pinView;
 }
```

but am not getting the image for MKAnnoation.What is wrong am doing?Please help me.

Comment: follow this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/2847/introduction-to-mapkit-on-ios-tutorial

Comment: Problem is simply that you are creating an MKPinAnnotationView instead of a MKAnnotationView.  You shouldn't need to do all drawInRect stuff in the answer.

Comment: ya.that was the mistake I did.Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have the same issue. Now using the working version as given below.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[Annotation class]])
    {
        static NSString* SFAnnotationIdentifier = @"SFAnnotationIdentifier";
        MKPinAnnotationView* pinView =
        (MKPinAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:SFAnnotationIdentifier];
        if (!pinView)
        {
            MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                                             reuseIdentifier:SFAnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];
            annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

            UIImage *flagImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map_pin.png"];

            CGRect resizeRect;

            resizeRect.size = flagImage.size;
            CGSize maxSize = CGRectInset(self.view.bounds,
                                         10.5,
                                         10.5).size;
            maxSize.height -= self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + 40.0;
            if (resizeRect.size.width > maxSize.width)
                resizeRect.size = CGSizeMake(maxSize.width, resizeRect.size.height / resizeRect.size.width * maxSize.width);
            if (resizeRect.size.height > maxSize.height)
                resizeRect.size = CGSizeMake(resizeRect.size.width / resizeRect.size.height * maxSize.height, maxSize.height);

            resizeRect.origin = (CGPoint){0.0f, 0.0f};
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(resizeRect.size);
            [flagImage drawInRect:resizeRect];
            UIImage *resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

            annotationView.image = resizedImage;
            annotationView.opaque = NO;

            UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

            Annotation *annoterObject = (Annotation *) annotation;

            rightButton.tag = annoterObject.annoteCount;

            [rightButton addTarget:self
                            action:@selector(showDetails:)
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

            return annotationView;
        }
        else
        {
            pinView.annotation = annotation;
        }
        return pinView;
    }

    return nil;

}
```

This is the working code.

Answer (score 0):

Where you have to set image?is it on callouts? if yes replace  `[pinView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flag2.png"]];` with `pinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = [[ UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flag2.png"]];`