# iOS MKAnnotation multiple pin types

Tags: ios, mapkit, core-location

I start my question with a reference to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407427/setting-image-for-mkannotation)

I can add a custom annotation image, but I want to be able to choose different images for different types of place. At present, all annotations show, but they all use the same image. Can someone please look at my code to see what I'm missing or doing incorrectly.

This is the header for my annotation subclass:

```
@interface DDBusAnnotation: NSObject <MKAnnotation> {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    NSString *title;
    NSString *subtitle;
    NSString *routeNumber;
    NSString *imageName;
    NSString *type;
}
```

This is the (UPDATED) viewForAnnotation method:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    //NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

    NSString *annotationImageName = [[NSString alloc] init];

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        [mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeNone animated:NO];
        return nil;  //return nil to use default blue dot view
    }

    //NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@", (DDAnnotation*)annotation];
    //NSLog(@" DDAnnotation  : %@", temp );


    if ([((DDAnnotation*)annotation).type isEqualToString:@"bus"]) {
        annotationImageName = @"bus.png";
    }

    if ([((DDAnnotation*)annotation).type isEqualToString:@"train"]) {
        annotationImageName = @train.png";
    }
```

Comment: Forgot.. The user location image is correct, and all images show "station.png"

Comment: Are you sure annotations of type DDBusAnnotation are being created?  By any chance, is DDBusAnnotation a subclass of DDStationAnnotation?

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. I've updated my code to only have one subclass - and I check for "type" in that class. No joy yet. To answer you specifically, I've added the header of the subclass to my question.

Comment: In viewForAnnotation, NSLog the type and title of the annotation.  Make sure the type value is what it's expecting.  Put breakpoints or NSLog on/before the "= bus.png" and "= train.png" lines and make sure they are being hit for the right annotations.

Comment: hmm. I'm showing 11 buses and 80 trains which is about right. I am actually showing only 1 bus on the map. Maybe I'll make my map span smaller so I can count to see if the pins match the counters. I don't know how to log the annotation type. That, and more ideas, are very welcome.

Comment: `NSLog(@"type=%@, title=%@", ((DDAnnotation*)annotation).type, annotation.title);`.  For testing purposes, comment out the actual code and add test code that just creates one "bus" and one "train".

Comment: Thanks a lot for the logging help. I got it working but I wish I could tell you how. I think I may have over-initialized the annotation arrays. I also tweaked spans.